# Apache HttpClient returning SocketTimeout exception for resource not found URL

Tags: java, http

I am trying to download images using apache http client.For one url which is resource not found(404) ,apache httpclient returning intermittently either 404 or sockettimeout exception.

Can anyone help me understand why for same url it is returning two different response.

Below is my config value

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                   .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                   .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                   .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                   .setMaxRedirects(3)
                   .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false)
                   .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC))
                   .build();

Future<HttpResponse> httpResponseFuture = asyncCloseableHttpClient.execute(httpUriRequest, null);
       try {
           return httpResponseFuture.get();
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           Throwable cause = e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : e;
         
           if (cause instanceof ConnectException) {

               throw new DownloadConnectionException("ConnectionException " + cause, IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, cause);
           }
           if (cause instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
               
               throw new DownloadTimeoutException(DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION);
           }
           if (cause instanceof ConnectionClosedException) {
               
               throw new DownloadConnectionClosedException("ConnectionClosedException " + cause, IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, cause);
           }
           if(cause instanceof UnsupportedCharsetException) {
               
                             throw new BadRequestException("Image download failed with UnsupportedCharsetException " + cause,
                   INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE_EXCEPTION, cause);
           }
           if (cause instanceof CircuitBreakerOpenException)
               throw cause;

           throw new BadRequestException("Image download failed: " + e.getMessage(),
               IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, cause);
       }
```

URL that I am trying to access: *https://decalpitstop.com/ca/citruschevron-sagnpro12.jpg*

Comment: You'll want to post a minimal, yet complete, example that demonstrates the problem. This is certainly minimal but it's not complete and therefore not *easily* reproducible.

Comment: Agree with @JeffHolt. Please provide a reproducible example. Just now tried this, it works as expected with always returning 404 status code.

Comment: @JeffHolt @ Nagaraj Tantri updated with code

Comment: Because sometimes it timesout and sometimes now ;) Maybe load balancer is involved, or heavy traffic

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes it timesout and sometimes not. There is nothing in the code that would cause suc behavior, so it must be a infrastruycture issue. Maybe load balancer is involved, or heavy traffic. It also looks like you are using proxy, so it might be proxy causing the issue as well. Also it might fail at some redirects (you are following max 3). There is plenty of possibilities.

Turn on apache debug logs to see actual transmission that is beeing made. This should give you an insight on what is going on